# Using IIS server and wamp server on same machine

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I am using windows 7 and wamp server 2.2, I have installed the wamp server and i have already installed IIS server now when i access localhost always IIS server is loading but i want to use wamp server instead of IIS server.

thanks in advance

Comment: As a side not, why you're not installing PHP for IIS? This will eliminate the neccessity of installing apache server and you may run your PHP applications with IIS .

Comment: @KiranRS thanks for your suggestion but at that time I had no choice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to run them both together, you need to run one on a different port.

For WAMP/Apache, change httpd.conf

```
listen 80
```

to

```
listen 81
```

(or some other unused port number).  Then to access, you'd go to

```
http://localhost:81/
```

Comment: Path of `httpd.conf`: `...\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.39\conf`

Answer (score 3):

In wamp server change your listening port to 80 to some other like 8080 and start all service
basicaly you find this in apache httpd config file.